# Flask and Jinja for loop skip if file contains errors

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm having a issue where I am trying to display some thumbs.  The problem is that when I run the jinja2 with the variable it displays the alt text, I would rather have it skip or pass if the thumb contains errors instead of displaying alt text.

Here is code

```
{% block content %}
      {% if games %}
        {% for g in games if g.game_thumb %}
             <img src="static{{ g.game_thumb }}" class="img-rounded" alt="{{ g.game_name }}" width="150" height="150">
        {%endfor%}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this via the flask route via.

```
from PIL import Image
    try:
        Image.open(thumb).verify()
        print "image"
    except:
        print "failed"
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way and propably more efficient, would be to use image preloading. Pass the src list to javascript through a data attribute or render to a javascript variable. Using javascript you can preload the images and discard the ones that do not load.

You can also simply handle `onerror` on `img` which is called when it fails to load, and hide/remove the images.